# How to move specific elements in and between lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

guys. I am now working on a python algorithm to build some inequalities. I'd like to ***move variables start with "x" to the left and move all the constants to the right and sum them***.

```
constraint_1 = str(boundNode[j]) + " + " + str(boundNode[j-(2*(i+1))]) + " <= " + str(boundNode[(j-(2*(i+1))+i)]) + " + " + str(boundNode[(j-(2*(i+1))+i)+1])
            test = constraint_1.split(" <= ")
            part_left = list(test[0].partition(" + "))
            part_right = list(test[1].partition(" + ")) 
            print(part_left, part_right)
```

This is what I have coded.

```
['x1', ' + ', '0'] ['4', ' + ', '6']
['x2', ' + ', '4'] ['7', ' + ', 'x1']
['x3', ' + ', '6'] ['x1', ' + ', '12']
['x4', ' + ', '7'] ['9', ' + ', 'x2']
['x5', ' + ', 'x1'] ['x2', ' + ', 'x3']
['x6', ' + ', '12'] ['x3', ' + ', '16']
['x7', ' + ', '9'] ['11', ' + ', 'x4']
['x8', ' + ', 'x2'] ['x4', ' + ', 'x5']
['x9', ' + ', 'x3'] ['x5', ' + ', 'x6']
['x10', ' + ', '16'] ['x6', ' + ', '19']
['x11', ' + ', '11'] ['13', ' + ', 'x7']
['x12', ' + ', 'x4'] ['x7', ' + ', 'x8']
['x13', ' + ', 'x5'] ['x8', ' + ', 'x9']
['x14', ' + ', 'x6'] ['x9', ' + ', 'x10']
['x15', ' + ', '19'] ['x10', ' + ', '22']
['20', ' + ', '13'] ['14', ' + ', 'x11']
['23', ' + ', 'x7'] ['x11', ' + ', 'x12']
['25', ' + ', 'x8'] ['x12', ' + ', 'x13']
['26', ' + ', 'x9'] ['x13', ' + ', 'x14']
['27', ' + ', 'x10'] ['x14', ' + ', 'x15']
['28', ' + ', '22'] ['x15', ' + ', '25']
```

This is what I received in terminal.

For example, the ideal output of the 2nd line would be
`-x1 + x2 <= 3`

What i am looking forward here is an approach to find all the index of elements contain `"x"` with a loop or condition statement.

Comment: this is not a good idea.  What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: if you're trying to parse/solve algebraic systems, have a look at `sympy`.  If you want to evaluate inequalities, use a function.  If you tell us what your objective is, we can help for sure

Comment: @anon01 Yeah I don't think it can work. I am trying to generate inequalities like `-x1 + x2 <= 3` which is equal to the second line of the output in terminal provided above. By the way. There is a `` <= `` in each line.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, code is supposed to make things easy/concise.  If you have to "hard code" many lines for one bit of logic, there's probably an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question as stated but is probably more useful and too long to post in a comment.  Try this instead:

```
def my_ineq(x1, x2):

    if -x1 + x2 <= 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False

my_ineq(2,4) # True
my_ineq(0,5) # False
```